# Which source file contains ?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle

Tags: android

I hope to view the source file which defines `?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle`, where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sources are located at `android-sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/`. For example, using android-8 platform, start with the `themes.xml`, look for the line

```
<item name="spinnerItemStyle">@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
```

You can see it is defined in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
</style>
```

where it references another line within the same file:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>
</style>
```

where it references a value from `colors.xml` this time. From there you can dig on until you get what you want.